# What is the difference between "lay" and "lie"?

Tags: verbs, differences, confusables, lie-lay-lain-laid

How do I know when to use *lay* and when to use *lie*, and what are the different forms of each verb? I'm always getting them confused.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The verb *lay* is transitive.

> You lay something on the table.

The verb *lie* is intransitive.

> You lie on the table when you are
>   operated upon.

The confusion comes because the past tense of *lie* is *lay*:

> He lay on the table for two hours before he was operated upon.

Few native speakers get this right. Most people would say, "He laid on the table for two hours." Bill Clinton constantly made this mistake in speeches.

Comment: what about "lied", "laid", and "lain"?

Comment: it's **lie/lay/has lain** and **lay/laid/has laid**, so (1) "lied" is not part of this issue, it is the past tense of "to lie" as in to tell a fib as in "he lied to me yesterday" and (2) he "he laid the plate on the table yesterday", and (3) "he has lain on the table for three hours"

Comment: reading this: http://web.ku.edu/~edit/lie.html and repeating these to yourself for a couple days can correct years of fossilized bad grammar regarding lie, lie and lay

Comment: I thing it's over-egging it to say 'few native speakers get this right', unless you have some source which demonstrates that. It may vary in different areas, but I don't hear 'laid' for 'lay' often, if ever.

Comment: @Spagirl Across regional Britain I'm sure people frequently say "He laid in bed all day"

Comment: @WS2 'Frequently' yes, but the question states 'few native speakers get this right' which casts those who *do* get it correct as a minority. I don't think that is an accurate reflection, I didn't say it didn't happen.

Comment: @Spagirl I would almost be prepared to bet money that they are a minority.

Comment: @WS2 It may Scotland my part of the world 'lie' is (or was in the 50s) more commonly used in eg 'I am going to lie down' while in the SE it is absent. It also notes that in the 17th and 18th centuries substituting lie with lay was not considered a solecism. So perhaps people are just speaking like they always did, but some beggar has decided that its wrong now.

Comment: The misuse of _lay_ for _lie_ seems to outweigh correct usage, at least from my U.S. perspective.  Using _lay_ as an intransitive verb is ubiquitous in conversation, news articles, television shows and movies, and even in some novels.  (I understand when a character makes this error in dialogue, but not when that same character pedantically corrects others on grammar and usage.)  I won't be surprised if some American dictionary soon decides to list _lay_ as an acceptable synonym of _lie_.

Comment: Why don't you provide sample sentences with the principle parts? What's the point otherwise?

Answer (score 21):

Historically, "lay" is a causitive verb formed from "lie", by a process which is now obsolete in English, but has left some other examples: "rise/raise" and "fall/fell".

In the case of "lie", probably because both words are common and the past of "lie" happens to be the same as the present of "lay", they have become generally confused, and for many people they are no longer distinct.

I don't know why the same has not happened to "fall" and "fell", but it may be simply because the verb "fell" is not very common, being used only of trees and enemies.

Comment: Another historical intransitive–causative pair is *sit/set*. These days you can sit people though. :)

Comment: True, @tchrist.

Answer (score 13):

These English verbs give an incredible amount of trouble for everyone,
mostly because people are not told the simple truth about them. Here it is:

1. *Lie, lay, lain* is an irregular intransitive inchoative verb
   meaning 'to assume a recumbent (horizontal) position'
   *The cat is lying on the mat. Lie down and take a nap. He lay down and died.*
2. *Sit, sat, sat* is an irregular intransitive inchoative verb
   meaning 'to assume a sitting (bent) position'
   *The cat is sitting on the mat. Sit down and have some tea. He sat down and ate.*
3. *Rise, rose, risen* is an irregular intransitive inchoative verb
   meaning 'to assume a standing (vertical) position'
   *The man is rising from his seat. Rise up and tell the story. He rose and spoke.*

All of these positions are defined with respect to the human body, and human subjects are prototypical for these verbs; non-human subjects (*The tide is rising*) are metaphorical.
In each case, since they are intransitive, these verbs have no direct object.

Inchoative verbs refer to a change of state. With these verbs the states are physical.
As usual, however, when there is an intransitive inchoative verb for a particular state,
there is also a transitive causative verb, meaning to **cause** a change of state.
The subject of a causative verb is what causes the change of state,
and the object is what undergoes the change of state.

These three inchoative verbs **each** have a related causative verb:

1. *Lay, laid, laid* is the causative of *lie, lay, lain.* It is regular, not irregular.
   *He is laying the rat on the mat. Lay it down carefully. He laid himself down and died.*
2. *[Set, set, set](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/169730/15299)* is the causative of *sit, sat, sat.* Like *sit*, it's irregular, but not the same way.
   *He is setting the statue on the mat. Set it down carefully. He set it down and waited.*
3. *Raise, raised, raised* is the causative of *rise, rose, risen*. It is regular.
   *They are raising the flagpole today. Raise it higher, please. He raised himself up.*

A graphic depiction of a fraction of the network of *lie/lay* [is shown here](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/threekindsofword.pdf).
Similar graphics could be made for *sit/set* and *rise/raise.* There's a lot going on.

Comment: You could make a living doing this.

Comment: I did, for 50 years. This is the result.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you very much for that, John. But do I understand that the causative 'lay'has to be transitive? If so what about 'The hens are laying'. Is it that 'eggs' are regarded as an implied object, or is 'lay' when applied to eggs a different verb?

Comment: Yes, there are implied objects just as there are implied subjects. And implied indirect objects also. Furthermore, there are implied circumstances (time, place, etc) for any sentence, which may be referred to as well. Transitivity is mostly a feature of clauses instead of verbs, but occasionally there is a lexical difference between a transitive causative and an intransitive inchoative (like _kill_ vs _die_), and in that case one assumes there is an object and figures out what it has to be. In other cases, like causative _open_ vs inchoative _open,_ the presence of an object determines.

Comment: And implied compliments.

Answer (score 10):

The notion that most native speakers are making a mistake about how to use language is ludicrous in the extreme. To paraphrase the linguist Dwight Bolinger, the only possible way that language can be made and defined is by how native speakers, in the broadest sense, use it.

To suggest that the majority are making a mistake completely rules out the idea that languages can change. As we all know, languages do change, so that makes the other notion fatuous.

In this case, it isn't an issue of language change. It's simply another bad prescription; actually, using 'bad' is redundant as a prescription is always bad.

> <sub>[Usage discussion of **lay** from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay):]</sub>
>
> *lay* has been used intransitively in the sense of “lie” since the 14th century. The practice was unremarked until around 1770; attempts to correct it have been a fixture of schoolbooks ever since. Generations of teachers and critics have succeeded in taming most literary and learned writing, but intransitive *lay* persists in familiar speech and is a bit more common in general prose than one might suspect. Much of the problem lies in the confusing similarity of the principal parts of the two words. Another influence may be a folk belief that *lie* is for people and *lay* is for things. Some commentators are ready to abandon the distinction, suggesting that *lay* is on the rise socially. But if it does rise to respectability, it is sure to do so slowly: many people have invested effort in learning to keep *lie* and *lay* distinct. Remember that even though many people do use *lay* for *lie*, others will judge you unfavorably if you do.

Answer (score 1):

I love pictures in [You Tube video](https://www.vocabulary.cl/english/lay-lie-difference.htm). A picture thousand words!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

LynnMiclea.com

[Grammar Tips and Tidbits](https://www.lynnmiclea.com/grammar-tips.html)

Lie versus Lay

Lie and lay are terms that people often mix up. They are not interchangeable; they have different meanings and should be used properly.

Lie means to rest or recline and is an intransitive verb, meaning it does not take an object. You lie down, he lies on the bed, she lies on the floor.

Lay means to put or place and is a transitive verb, meaning it needs an object. You lay something down, he lays the book down, she lays the file on the table, they lay down the law.