# Using 'stuck' as a verb

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech

> The visual studio kept stucking under RDP yesterday

Should 'stuck' become a present tense verb? It seems like "getting stuck" is too long for the modern world where it happens much more frequently to things than it used to (See, for example, Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy, "Share and enjoy").

Comment: What would be the benefit over the commonly accepted present tense "sticking"?

Comment: This sounds like a case of improper use of a word.  Substitute that with "posted", "moved", "assigned", etc., and the sentence works well.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the answer should be **no** since the usage of 'stuck' (in the case of getting, being stuck) is as a modifier. A similar case could be made for "I am happy", as though 'am happy' should be a verb. It would see an equal amount of use; but structurally being a verb doesn't simplify anything or make it more concise/accurate.

Comment: My computer never sticks. It sometimes gets stuck, but mostly it just hangs [around, doing nothing].

Answer (score 3):

Well, such things are possible in language.  You are talking about taking an adjective/a past participle of a verb and re-appropriating it as the present tense of a verb with a related, but different, meaning.  This verb seems to refer specifically to programs/computers getting stuck.  Sure, this could happen.  As to whether it is likely, it really depends on circumstances -- it is similar to asking if a certain animal should evolve a sharper claw.  If there is sufficient need for it, and if there isn't a better alternative, then it will emerge -- but language change doesn't happen because people decide it.

Linguistically speaking, creating a verb (to stuck) that looks like the past tense form of another verb (to stick) is not impossible.  As mentioned in [another thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/difference-between-lay-and-lie/1492#1492), we have the verbs "to fall/to fell", "to lay/to lie".

The biggest obstacle I see is competing terms that already exist as verbs: "to hang" and "to lag" come to mind.  Both of these are related to "getting stuck" in the computer sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have never before encountered this use, but there do seem to be a few examples on Google. Some are probably mistypes, but it does look as if there are people using it in this way. Perhaps it will become established, but I doubt it.

What is clear, though, is that there is very little that you or I could do either to make it happen or to stop it happening. Change in language just happens when it happens, and it is rare that an individual can influence that.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic phrase is *to get stuck* (meaning to hang, to bog down, to stop), where the verb is *to get*, so that's the term that needs to be modified for time -- hence *got stuck,* *kept getting stuck*, etc. *Stuck* is, as noted, an adjective in this case.

It's true that *to stick* is also a verb, and it's arguable that in some circumstances, *to stick* and *to get stuck* might be synonymous. Not here, though, because in the context (computers), we don't say that the computer or program *stuck*.