# When is the proper time to use "lie" vs "lay"

Tags: verbs, lie-lay-lain-laid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “lay” and “lie”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-the-difference-between-lay-and-lie)

Which one of the following examples is correct?

1. Lie down on the bench.
2. Lay down on the bench.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important distinction is that *lay* requires a direct object and *lie* does not. So you *lie down on the sofa* (no direct object), but you *lay the book down on the table* (the book is the direct object).

Comment: There are also some complications when you are dealing with the past tense of "lie" which is "lay" and it shouldn't be mistaken for "lay" in present tense.

Comment: You could also just lay (yourself) down on the sofa. (By the same logic)