# Show I use "lay," "laid," or "lain" in the following passage?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, lie-lay-lain-laid

> The ground was ice-cold, no hint of anyone having lay/laid/lain there
>   at all.

Which one is the correct option?

Comment: It should be "lain". Just look up your dictionary :)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/153332/15299

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "lay" and "lie"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-the-difference-between-lay-and-lie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
to lay - laid - laid - /to put something down/
to lie - lay - lain - /to rest or recline/
to lie - lied - lied - /to deceive, not tell the truth/
```

*Lay* is not an option, since grammatically a past participle is required in your context and *lay* isn't the past participle of anything.

If you consider *laid*, then you get an incomplete sentence. Anyone having laid what? Remember, *laid* is the past participle of *lay*, which is a transitive verb, and as such requires a direct object which is missing in your sentence.

You need *lain* which is the past participle of *lie*.

> The ground was ice-cold, no hint of anyone having lain there at all.

Comment: [Diagram here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf)