# Lie or lay dead?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, lie-lay-lain-laid

The context is

> "The mercenaries lie/lay dead."
>
> "The animal lies/lays dead."

It's present tense and there's a corpse involved.

I've looked it up elsewhere and I just don't understand the rules. Something about an object? Is a corpse an object?

Comment: There's a comprehensive answer at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-the-difference-between-lay-and-lie.  But it's genuinely confusing, and native speakers often get it wrong.  In particular, although the expression "Lay down and die" is incorrect, it's used so commonly (as a metaphor for giving up completely) that it's arguably become acceptable as a stock phrase.

Comment: _Lie_ is am intransitive bverb, so it can't have an object. _There he lies, dead as a doornail_. _Lay_ is the transitive causative form of _lie_; i.e, _lay_ means 'cause to lie', so it can have an object. _We will lay him there, in the crypt_. That's the simple part. The complicated part is that _to lie_ is an irregular verb, whereas _to lay_ is regular. Result: the past tense of _lay_ is _laid_ (_We laid him there_), **but** the past tense of _lie_ is also pronounced (and spelled) _lay_ (_There he lay_). [Word-form details here.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand any of that. I can look up the grammatical explanations and they all sound very comprehensive, but I'm stupid so I had to ask for the correct answer. *Transitive causative* is just gobbledygook to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough, once you understand it.  Not too simple if you don't.

To begin with, the answer:

If it is really the present tense, you must use **lie(s)**.

Here are some of the difficulties:

1. This type of sentence is rarely used in the simple present.  The simple present tense is only used when something is always, or habitually, so.  But mercenaries always lying dead is not a likely scenario.  This type of sentence requires the simple past if it already happened, in which case the verb is **lay(s)**, or if it's happening now, the present continuous, in which case the verb is **is/are lying**.
2. There are three verbs with overlapping forms that confuse people:  to **lay**, which means to put something down something, to **lie**, usually used with **down** after it, which means to assume a horizontal position, such as we do on a bed, and also a second verb to **lie**, which means to tell a falsehood.  To make things worse, the past of to **lay** is **laid**, which is a word that is avoided by some people because it may be used as a somewhat vulgar slang term for having sex with someone. The past of **lie** (down) is **lay** (down), and the past of the other **lie** is simply **lied**.
3. You're confusing an everyday object with a grammatical object.  An everyday object is just a thing...a pen, a hamburger, a hand.  A grammatical object is something that receives the action of the verb, and usually follows it. It may be a thing or a person. Yo use the verb **lay**, we need a **grammatical** object, but it can be a thing or a person: "I laid **my pen** down". "I laid **the baby** down to sleep".  Notice that if I myself did the same thing, there is no object in the sentence, and I'd say "I **lay** down, but I'd be using the verb to **lie** down in the past, not the verb to **lay**.

Comment: It's from a game. There is the battle sequence, and immediately after the beginning of the description of the aftermath. "The animal is lying dead" just sounds wrong somehow, but it is in the present.  2. I'm not sure because it's a corpse. A corpse can't lie down. It has been struck down and now it lies/lays/is laying dead, but *is laying/is lying* just sounds wrong to me. I don't know.

Comment: Lie is intransitive. That means no object. The animal is just lying there.  It's true that corpses cannot lie down (which implies movement from one position to another), but they can be lying dead.