# Confused while reading Stephen King's Pet Sematary: "It just went feet up one day"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> But if it’s all the time crossing back and forth, its luck will run out, and it’ll end up there with the Ryder kids’ coon and little Timmy Dessler’s cocker spaniel and Missus Bradleigh’s parakeet. Not that the parakeet got run over in the road, you understand. **It just went feet up one day.**

Really confused what did he mean? His feet were blowed?

Comment: It shuffled off its mortal coil.

Comment: Picture a parakeet laying on the bottom of the cage with its feet sticking up in the air.

Comment: Have you heard of the expression:  “he turned up his toes”? It is a roundabout way of saying: “he died”.  Probably it comes from the traditional way  in which the dead are laid out:  face up, an so toes up.

Comment: In computerdom, back in the days of blinking monsters on hollow floors, the term "casters up" meant the computer had died.

Comment: Nah, it's just resting!

Comment: @HotLicks  You mean **lying** on the bottom of the cage!

Comment: @KateBunting - You think he was being dishonest?

Comment: @HotLicks See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-the-difference-between-lay-and-lie

Comment: @KateBunting - You're implying that the bird was there of its own volition.

Comment: @HotLicks This is getting silly. The bird would be **lying** dead, unless we picture someone **laying** it out on the cage floor.

Answer (score 1):

"Feet up" - for  bird, would mean it was dead.

When a bird dies, we often think it lies on its back with its feet up in air...Especially if it dies of natural causes...

Comment: Works for people too (though usually lying on ones back means sleeping :o)).