# Word to describe a faint, feeble, and irregular sound?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word (adjective) to describe a sound that is very weak and coming in and out. It may also be used to describe a dying heartbeat that is inconstant and indicative of imminent death. I initially thought the word was "feathery," but Google tells me that's totally off base; I mention it, nonetheless, on the off chance that the two words are similar and it may better facilitate your recall of the *right* word. Also, I'm fairly certain the word ends in -y.

The word should fit the following sentence -

> The soldier's breath was _____ as he lay bleeding, dying.

Comment: Separate issue, but I think you want "The soldier ... lay" (past tense of lie). See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-the-difference-between-lay-and-lie

Comment: There are an awful lot of written instances in Google Books saying someone's  [*breath **fluttered***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22breath+fluttered%22). But there is no "right" answer - it's a stylistic choice / matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2):

**fitful**

> often stopping and starting and not happening in a regular or
> continuous way:
>
> fitful breathing
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fitful

Answer (score 1):

## Faltering

From [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=faltering),

> losing strength or momentum.
> "his faltering career"
> speaking hesitantly.
> "she tells her plight in faltering tones"
>
> moving unsteadily or hesitantly.
> "he is now all set to take his first faltering steps"

as it implies a sense of weakness as well…

“The soldier drew his last **faltering** breaths as he lay bleeding, dying.

Answer (score 0):

I would say ***faint***:

> Low in volume or barely audible
>
> - She heard a ***faint*** noise in the deckhead, like a distant flag flapping in the breeze. ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/faint.html))

Since you specified that it must end in ***-y***, I also thought ***weary*** might be appropriate in this context:

> Feeling or showing extreme tiredness, especially as a result of excessive exertion ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/weary.html#C0-1))

As you can see from this [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weary%20breath%2Chis%20breath%20was%20weary%2C%20faint%20breath%2Chis%20breath%20was%20faint&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweary%20breath%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfaint%20breath%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20breath%20was%20faint%3B%2Cc0), both ***faint breath*** and ***weary breath*** are used, but "faint prevails".

I found ***faint*** used in a text on [this site](http://www.markedbyteachers.com/as-and-a-level/psychology/the-river-was-roaring-past-the-children-and-their-teacher-as-the-group-of-kids-tried-in-vain-to-understand-the-teacher-s-inaudible-mutterings.html):

> All the colour had gone from his cheeks ***and his breath was faint***.

As for ***weary*** I found that "to draw a weary breath" is more common than "his breath was weary". So you could say:

> The soldier drew ***a weary breath/weary breaths*** as he lay bleeding out.

Answer (score 0):

I woould like to correct you, it is in the past tense, so it is lay, not lie.

Try shuddering, or faint.

Shuddering

> The soldier's breath was **shuddering** as he lay bleeding out.

Shuddering definition in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjo1PytkrTuAhV273MBHSulDCwQFjAJegQIIRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.cambridge.org%2Fdictionary%2Fenglish%2Fshuddering&usg=AOvVaw1rprq80zOGaUS_JUNABKbp).

Faint

> The soldier's breath was **faint** as he lay bleeding out.

Faint meaning in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiHlq7Zk7TuAhU5_3MBHVMZB4gQFjASegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.cambridge.org%2Fdictionary%2Fenglish%2Ffaint&usg=AOvVaw3YPFK06UnuigsZa5Uy45eu).

Answer (score 0):

While **feathery** generally refers to physical form or texture, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feathery) gives one meaning of the word as "soft and delicate", and this does not necessarily refer to something which has a similar appearance to a feather.

Cambridge includes the example "The still centre of the piece was 'snowfall on ashes', as caressing, feathery string tremolo harmonics traced a patina of frost on which the soloist skated nervously." So it can be used (perhaps metaphorically) to refer to sound.

It is slightly an odd word to use to describe a dying man's breathing, because it has connotations of being tender, nice to the touch, and pleasant. But it could have a degree of irony - dying or dead people are often described as looking peaceful or at rest, and feathers have a similar connotation.

Answer (score -1):

**Waning**, **abating**, or **dwindling**.